# How to write interfaces for a golang function if one of the methods returns another instance of the type?

Tags: go, design-patterns, interface, mocking

How should we write interfaces in golang when a type wants to return an instance of the same type (whether that be a different instance or just the same instance)?

I think it's easier to set the context of the question via an example. I am trying to implement something like a logger library in Golang. This has a bunch of logging functions (`Log` in the implementation given below), and a few functions to set an internal context (stuff like structured log parameters, request context, etc, `WithContext` in the example). This is provided as a library for some consumers.

The consumers of the library make an initial logger instance, and then passes the logger through functions, calling `WithContext` on the logger to add additional parameters to the logs. (This is the first example). So far so good.

Now, the consumers want to write custom mocks for the Logger, since some of them want the logs to be silent, while others want to do something in the Log functions. So they write an interface `ILogger` which is accepted by the functions, so they can continue running the code as before. The catch now is with how `ILogger` should specify the `WithContext` function. If `ILogger.WithContext` returns a concrete type, then you cannot mock the logger. On the other hand, if `ILogger.WithContext` returns an `ILogger`, the concrete type complains that it doesn't implement `ILogger`.

More generally, how would we tackle cases where we want to return an instance of the object type itself, but want the ability to mock it manually? This is a common pattern used in, for example, chaining in builders, deep copy functions, etc.

#### Minimal Reproduction

**Code for the context**

Here, no interface used, but mocking the Logger isn't possible as the concrete type is passed): [Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/eI6U-ji8VKS)

```golang
type ActualLogger struct {
    Context string
}

func (a *ActualLogger) Log(msg string) {
    fmt.Printf("%s: %s\n", a.Context, msg)
}
func (a *ActualLogger) WithContext(c string) *ActualLogger {
    newInst := &ActualLogger{
        Context: c,
    }
    return newInst
}

// consumer
func anotherFunc(l *ActualLogger) {
    logger := l.WithContext("anotherFunc")
    logger.Log("hi")
}
func main() {
    logger := &ActualLogger{
        Context: "main",
    }
    logger.Log("hello")
    anotherFunc(logger)
}
```

**Interface with concrete return**

Here, an interface is used, but the `WithContext` function returns a concrete type in the interface. Here, we cannot write mocks properly, since the return of `WithContext` still has to be the concrete type and can't be our mock: [Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/EMLqsLEUYFF)

```golang
// logging library
type ActualLogger struct {
    Context string
}
func (a *ActualLogger) Log(msg string) {
    fmt.Printf("%s: %s\n", a.Context, msg)
}
func (a *ActualLogger) WithContext(c string) *ActualLogger {
    newInst := &ActualLogger{
        Context: c,
    }
    return newInst
}

// consumer
type ILogger interface {
    Log(msg string)
    WithContext(c string) *ActualLogger
}
func anotherFunc(l ILogger) {
    logger := l.WithContext("anotherFunc")
    logger.Log("hi")
}
func main() {
    logger := &ActualLogger{
        Context: "main",
    }
    logger.Log("hello")
    anotherFunc(logger)
}
```

**Interface returns interface**

Here, the interface `ILogger` has `WithContext` return an `ILogger`. However, the `ActualLogger.WithContext` is not determined by go to conform to `ILogger` since it does not return the `ILogger` type explicitly, even though the returned type of `*ActualLogger` conforms to `ILogger` excluding this one case. [Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/13tpcuYrEgw)

```golang
// logging library

type ActualLogger struct {
    Context string
}
func (a *ActualLogger) Log(msg string) {
    fmt.Printf("%s: %s\n", a.Context, msg)
}
func (a *ActualLogger) WithContext(c string) *ActualLogger {
    newInst := &ActualLogger{
        Context: c,
    }
    return newInst
}

// consumer
type ILogger interface {
    Log(msg string)
    WithContext(c string) ILogger
}
func anotherFunc(l ILogger) {
    logger := l.WithContext("anotherFunc")
    logger.Log("hi")
}
func main() {
    logger := &ActualLogger{
        Context: "main",
    }
    logger.Log("hello")
    // This won't work as ActualLogger.WithContext doesn't return a type of ILogger,
    // even though the returned type (*ActualLogger) does implement ILogger
    anotherFunc(logger)
}
```

This gives the error:

```bash
./prog.go:38:14: cannot use logger (variable of type *ActualLogger) as ILogger value in argument to anotherFunc: *ActualLogger does not implement ILogger (wrong type for method WithContext)
        have WithContext(string) *ActualLogger
        want WithContext(string) ILogger

Go build failed.
```

#### Possible Solution

The only "solution" I can think of is to change the pattern from injection to mutation:

```golang
// instead of,
newLogger := oldLogger.WithContext("xyz")

// do,
newLogger := NewLogger()
newLogger.SetContext(oldLogger.GetContext())
newLogger.AddContext("xyz")
```

However, this feels less elegant than the injection pattern.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Not sure what to cut out here, I think this is a single question. If anyone feels this can be split further, do let me know. Thanks!